# WiFi iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, wifi

im working on an iPhone application which requires communication between 2 devices through WiFi.

Can somebody please help me by providing a simple iphone application code for the same which is able to communicate data between the devices...i hv gone through the "**witap application**" available on the developers site but wasnt able to understand it...

please help..

Comment: Could you edit this and mention in the question that you're writing an iPhone application? I know it's tagged that way, but it would still be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great 2-part tutorial at MacResearch:

[Part One](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxviii-bonjour-and-how-do-you-do)

[Part Two](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxix-message)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bonjour , let Device A as the server, and publish service via Bonjour; and in Device B,use the NSNetServiceBrowser to search the published service via device A in the same local network,and connect by socket to send data.

there is a demo here.[download](http://www.cppblog.com/Files/kesalin/MacChatty.zip).And you can read this article [go>>](http://blog.csdn.net/kesalin/article/details/6779882).It helped me before.